# Error while running RAILS_ENV =production

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I developed rails application which is working fine in local and when i try to run in the production, i am getting the following:

> We're sorry, but something went wrong.
>
> If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.

This is the command i used for production:
**rails server -e production**

My environment.rb:

```
# Load the Rails application.
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the Rails application.
Rails.application.initialize!

ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'production'
```

Database.yml file:

```
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: invmanagement
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

Log file:

```
I, [2015-02-26T10:47:29.879832 #8203]  INFO -- : Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-02-26 10:47:29 +0530
F, [2015-02-26T10:47:29.887726 #8203] FATAL -- : 
PG::ConnectionBad (could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
):
  activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:888:in `initialize'
  activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:888:in `new'
  activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:888:in `connect'
  activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:568:in `initialize'
  activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `new'
  activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `postgresql_connection'
  activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:435:in `new_connection'
  activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:445:in `checkout_new_connection'
  activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:416:in `acquire_connection'
  activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:351:in `block in checkout'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
  activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:350:in `checkout'
  activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in `block in connection'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
  activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:264:in `connection'
  activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:541:in `retrieve_connection'
  activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
  activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
  activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:51:in `restore_query_cache_settings'
  activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:43:in `rescue in call'
  activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:32:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: Can you connect to your sql server from command line, and how do you do it ?

Comment: I am using "pg" in production. When I run **bundle exec rails console production** , i am getting the error as : **PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
 Is the server running locally and accepting
 connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?**

Comment: Didn't you specified Postgres username and password in database.yml file?

Comment: Is postgres running locally? Can you connect to it with other tools?